# Dot code: Determine left and right children

Tags: tree, graphviz, dot, red-black-tree

I want to make a Red-Black Tree in dot (GraphViz).
But I always have the problem with the placement of my nodes.

This is my code so far (it's not finished because of the placement troubles):

```
digraph G {
//graph [ratio=.48];
node [style=filled, color=black, shape=circle, width=.6
  fontname=Helvetica, fontweight=bold, fontcolor=white,
  fontsize=24, fixedsize=true];
  B1[label = 35];
    B2[label = 10];
    B3[label = 25];
  B4[label = 40];

  node [style=filled, color=red, shape=circle, width=.6
    fontname=Helvetica, fontweight=bold, fontcolor=white,
    fontsize=24, fixedsize=true];

    R1[label = 15];
    R2[label = 5];
    R3[label = 20];
    R4[label = 30];
    R5[label = 45];

    node  [label = "NIL", style=filled, color=black, shape=record, width=.4,height=.25,
      fontname=Helvetica, fontweight=bold, fontcolor=white,
      fontsize=16, fixedsize=true];
    N1[];
    N2[];
    N3[];
    N4[];
    N5[];
    N6[];
    N7[];
    N8[];
    N9[];
    N10[];

    B1 -> B4;
    B1 -> R1;
    R1 -> B2;
    R1 -> B3;
    B4 -> N1;
    B4 -> R5;

}
```

So what I get is this:

[image: Red Black Tree Output]

But what I want is this:

[image: Wanted Tree]

As you see my code switches the nodes 15 and 40, and 45 and NIL.

Even when I change the order in my code, the result doesn't alter.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like adding explicit (invisible) relation with the same rank solves the problem.
In this case:

```
{rank=same;  R1;B4;}
R1->B4 [style="invis"]
{rank=same;  R5;N1;}
N1->R5  [style="invis"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Order in which nodes appear on the graph depend on the order they are defined.

So if you want node (15) to be rendered before (40), you have to define first (15), then (40):

```
  R1[label = 15];
  B4[label = 40];
```

The other solution is to use invisible edges and `rank=same` attribute to position nodes, as @albert suggested, but I would recommend to use this approach only when you've exhausted all the natural ways of positioning like the above.

In this case you lose your neat style grouping, since you will have to define styles manually for (15) and [NIL] at least. But this is lesser evil.

All that said, my solution for your code:

```
digraph G {

node [style=filled, color=black, shape=circle, width=.6
  fontname=Helvetica, fontweight=bold, fontcolor=white,
  fontsize=24, fixedsize=true];

  B1[label = 35];
    R1[color=red label = 15];
    B2[label = 10];
    B3[label = 25];
    N1[label = "NIL", shape=record, width=.4,height=.25 fontsize=16];
  B4[label = 40];

    R2[color=red label = 5];
    R3[color=red label = 20];
    R4[color=red label = 30];
    R5[color=red label = 45];

    N2[label = "NIL", shape=record, width=.4,height=.25 fontsize=16];
    N3[label = "NIL", shape=record, width=.4,height=.25 fontsize=16];
    N4[label = "NIL", shape=record, width=.4,height=.25 fontsize=16];
    N5[label = "NIL", shape=record, width=.4,height=.25 fontsize=16];
    N6[label = "NIL", shape=record, width=.4,height=.25 fontsize=16];
    N7[label = "NIL", shape=record, width=.4,height=.25 fontsize=16];
    N8[label = "NIL", shape=record, width=.4,height=.25 fontsize=16];
    N9[label = "NIL", shape=record, width=.4,height=.25 fontsize=16];
    N10[label = "NIL", shape=record, width=.4,height=.25 fontsize=16];

    B1 -> B4;
    B1 -> R1;
    R1 -> B2;
    R1 -> B3;
    B4 -> N1;
    B4 -> R5;

}
```

Result:

[image: result]